# Combining service and repository layers

Tags: wcf, repository-pattern

I am creating a simple messaging system in WCF and have implemented a minimal repository called `MessageRepository`.

It implements the contract `IMessageRepository` which is as follows:

```
using System;
using Violet.Model.Entities;

namespace Violet.Model.Abstract
{
    public interface IMessageRepository
    {
        void DeliverMessage(string message_from, string message_to, string message_text);
    }
}
```

Now I am confused as to whether to implement a separate service layer `IService` which invokes the model layer to interact with the database or to decorate the `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` attributes on the IMessageRepository itself to minimize the layers in my application.

Which do you think is a better approach considering the application would grow over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it probably isn't a good idea to expose your Data Access layer directly via a service. By creating a real service, and simply using your Repository, you have the flexibility to change them independently.

In general this is called the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleResponsibilityPrinciple)